# Setting permissions in Fedora Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache, fedora

I am building a Fedora server (on VirtualBox right now). It is running Fedora 15.

I want my PHP script to be able to edit the contents of a file in the same folder it is in.

The PHP script and the file are in /home/user/public_html/

But, when I call "file_put_contents("./theFile.txt")" I get an error saying that it cannot open the stream, permission denied.

So, I have:
- Made the file permissions 0777.
- Made the folder permissions 0777.
- Added the "apache" user to the group "wheel".
- Changed the user folder permissions to 0771.
- Changed the owner of the public_html folder and the text file to "apache:apache".

I am at my wits end and I have idea what to do next. Suggestions?

Comment: Is [SELinux](http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/SELinux_FAQ/) forbidding the writing? Check `dmesg(1)` or `/var/log/audit/audit.log` or `/var/log/messages`, especially for lines including `AVC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SELinux is preventing you from writing out the file. See the `httpd_selinux(8)` man page for ways to work with/around it.

Comment: YES! This was exactly the problem. Fixed that up and now everything is normal!