# Permissions issue with Symfony2 on Apache 2.4, Fedora 22: 500 response on app.php, app_dev.php, config.php

Tags: linux, apache, symfony, fedora

I am running several sites on my local machine for development and have decided to give Symfony a go for my next project.

I have created a new symfony project under /var/www/hfs; I have changed ownership to $USER, permissions to 755, and have created a virtualhost thusly:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName hfs.local
    ServerAlias www.hfs.local

    DocumentRoot /var/www/hfs/web

    <Directory /var/www/hfs/web>
        Require all granted

         <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
            Options -MultiViews
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
            RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
        </IfModule>
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/hfs_error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/hfs_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

visiting hfs.local, /app.php, /app_dev.php, and /config.php all return a 500 error. The corresponding error log message is:

```
[Sat Sep 12 18:55:54.871088 2015] [:error] [pid 7182] [client 127.0.0.1:35725] PHP Warning:  Unknown: failed to open stream: Permission denied in Unknown on line 0
[Sat Sep 12 18:55:54.871140 2015] [:error] [pid 7182] [client 127.0.0.1:35725] PHP Fatal error:  Unknown: Failed opening required '/var/www/hfs/web/app.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in Unknown on line 0
```

I have double checked and from my knowledge (which is relatively poor, only been really working within a LAMP stack for ~4 months) all files should be accessible by the apache user. I even, in desperation, tried 777

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tyler  tyler  1182 Jul 31 08:45 app_dev.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tyler  tyler 10784 Jul 31 08:45 apple-touch-icon.png
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tyler  tyler  1014 Sep 12 19:35 app.php
drwxrwxrwx. 2 tyler  tyler  4096 Sep 12 17:09 bundles
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tyler  tyler  5746 Jul 31 08:47 config.php
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tyler  tyler    82 Sep 12 18:03 .directory
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tyler  tyler  6518 Jul 31 08:45 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tyler  tyler  3320 Jul 31 08:45 .htaccess
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 tyler  tyler   106 Jul 31 08:45 robots.txt
```

I am running three other flat php applications fine. Further, just cause, I've checked and /usr/share/pear is indeed global readable.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong with permissions, but I've quadruple checked the symfony docs, have tried changing ownership of the directory to apache user, and, if it's relevant, when using AllowOverride All, I'm told the .htaccess file can't be accessed -- despite having global read access.

Greatly appreciate your help, I've spent a few hours researching and have found nothing to help! Feeling quite the noob.

EDIT: For what it's worth, I had no trouble setting this up on a Debian install that is otherwise identical.

Comment: Do you have `.htaccess` in the right place? Does your server have proper `mod_rewrite` confirmation and is that module enabled?

Comment: Yes; it is in ../web/.htacess and if I attempt to use it rather than rewriting in the conf file, the error I get is     Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:36612] AH00529: /var/www/hfs/web/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/hfs/web/' is executable  -- both of these things are enabled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Being *particularly* new to Fedora, I had not encountered SELinux. More things to learn :)

I have somewhat naively shoved commands into my shell, feeling the taste of success being so close. It was a combination of these commands:

```
chcon -R -t httpd_sys_content_t hfs
chcon -R -t public_content_rw_t hfs/app/cache
chcon -R -t public_content_rw_t hfs/app/logs
setsebool -P allow_httpd_anon_write 1
```

[Setting permissions in Fedora Apache/PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033034/setting-permissions-in-fedora-apache-php?rq=1)

[Apache 403 error, (13)Permission denied: access to / denied, Fedora 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816836/apache-403-error-13permission-denied-access-to-denied-fedora-16?rq=1)

[Permission issue in cache and logs folder in Symfony 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11520370/permission-issue-in-cache-and-logs-folder-in-symfony-2-0)